# Where can I find ogr_FileGDB.dll v1.4 compilled for Windows?

Tags: ogr

Since v1.3 do not have custom CRS support, where can I find the ogr_FileGDB.dll v1.4 compiled for Windows?

Comment: Hello Brad Nesom. 
Download (done). Environment variables to C:\FileGDB_API_VS2010_1_4\bin and  C:\FileGDB_API_VS2010_1_4\lib (done). 
GDB > SHP (ok) with "ESRI Shapefile" drivers...
SHP > GDB (not ok) with "FileGDB"... Unable to find driver `FileGDB'
Thanks

Comment: You're asking a different question in comments.  Please either **edit the question** to include proper configuration, or ask a different question

Answer (score 1):

[OSGEO](http://osgeo.org) is the location to find most of the answers you are looking for.
There are quite a few tools compiled for windows in the [OsGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/)
Once you are signed in you can access the member page for [binary distribution](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/OSGeo_Binary_Distribution)
However you may have already discovered that there are limitations to the filegdb drivers.
under the [gdal/ogr](http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html) umbrella there is an earlier version.
There are esri (not open source) api for 1.4 [here](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/#File_Geodatabase_API_1.4)

Comment: Hello Brad
I just want to migrate shp to gdb and gdb to shp with python programming... and I use custom CRS... so, with the ogr_FileGDB.dll v1.3, I dont have data access... v1.4 yes, with custom CRS...

Comment: it is the gdb writer that is the sticky point. esri has it but unless I am mistaken nobody else does.

Comment: If I change to known crs, I can write, no problem...